# If a Jupiter-sized sphere of a translucent liquid were to suddenly appear, what would the inner core consist of? Would the planet refract light?

Tags: planet

Assuming Jupiter is suddenly replaced, or if a giant sphere of fruit juice or other translucent mixtures/liquids were to appear bearing a similar radius to that of Jupiter, hypothetically , what would be the contents of the inner core? Would the pressure there be so high as to rip the liquids into their constituent atoms? Would light from a Sun shining on this planet be refracted through the planet's translucent body?

Comment: You can't specify that fruit juice remains liquid if gathered into a Jupiter-sized sphere. Such a sphere would have roughly the mass of Jupiter and if the sphere is to be in equilibrium then the appropriate increase in pressure and density, with consequent phase changes, would be required.

Comment: Can you see the bottom of the ocean from a boat on the surface?

Comment: @ProfRob so would it (the inner portions) freeze over and be a solid  then due to increased pressure and density?

Comment: @HankRyan I really don't know and I doubt whether anybody has spent their time working out what happens to a Jupiter-mass of fruit juice. Jupiter is mainly made up of gases which you would class as "transparent" if at low density - hydrogen, helium.

Comment: @JamesK that's a good point. So I'm assuming it'd be just as foggy as say, jupiter then?

Comment: @ProfRob - I did spend some time analysing a similar case: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10553 (The pulp is basically fruit juice)

Comment: Even a sphere of pure water with a radius of a few kilometres would be fairly opaque. The [absorption length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_length) of water (for 418 nm blue light, where it's most transparent) is around 227 m. So, eg a slab of water 4 km thick only transmits $e^{-4000/277}\approx22.245\times 10^{-9}$, 22 billionths of the incoming light.

Comment: Indeed. It looks bizarre but it is not very different from existing planets. Beside the magic appearances and why you think one might see through, the physics would be similar to that of other molecules/planets. Even gas vs liquid isn't much dramatic difference by principle.

Answer (score 2):

A Jupiter made of fruit juice would probably allow sunlight to enter the first few metres below its surface, before being absorbed.  Just think how far light penetrates the water of the ocean. So you wouldn't be able to see the sun through it. It wouldn't act like a lens.

If you magically created it with uniform density, it would be very very far out of equilibium. The central parts would compress and release huge amounts of gravitational energy in the process.  The effect would probably be dramatic.

If you created it with a density and temperature gradient to keep it stable, you'd probably get a mantle of ice and water (including exotic high pressure ices) Depending on your exact temperature profile the water would be supercritical (it is indistinguishable from very high pressure steam, and there is no boiling point). The centre might be supported, at least in part, by electron degeneracy.

And (again depending on the exact parameter you choose) there could be a water vapour atmosphere.

As Rob says in a comment, "I doubt whether anybody has spent their time working out what happens to a Jupiter-mass of fruit juice." But we can look at a slightly smaller planet made out of ammonia and water: Neptune and Uranus are mostly water and ammonia ices, under a thick a hydrogen/helium atmosphere.

Comment: How would a uniform density cause it be out of equilibrium exactly?

Comment: The pressure must increase towards the centre, and if you pressurise something you compress it and increase the density. You can also increase pressure by raising the temperature. If you just have a ball of liquid, with no density changes, there will be unbalanced forces that will cause the core to compress, releaseing gravitational potential energy as heat... lots of it.

Comment: How does pressure work if its in the vaccum of space?

Comment: Its not the vacuum of space inside the planet!  The pressure is inside the planet, produced by the planet's own gravity.

Comment: and what about the outermost part of atmosphere  that touches space? Sorry, I don't know how to put it into words exactly